# WEBSITE_AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET must be set

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, kudu, azure-authentication

I am trying to call a function, and the problem is as soon as I run it on Azure Portal it says

> [Error] Executed 'SyncPhotos' (Failed,
> Id=f1100560-feb8-4f19-bf0e-678d9853092e, Duration=12ms)The Application
> Settings WEBSITE_AUTH_CLIENT_ID and WEBSITE_AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET must be
> set to perform this operation.

I can see via Kudu that I have `WEBSITE_AUTH_CLIENT_ID` set, however, `WEBSITE_AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET` is not set, and if I try to do it via application settings I am not allowed to do so.

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

ClientId and ClientSecret should be specified in the Azure portal under **'Authentication / Authorization'** of the web app settings.

When you want to set **CLIENT_SECRET**  you need to have the **Administrator  access of Azure Active Directory**. And also you need to specify the **identity provider**.

1)Select **Authentication** in the menu on the left. Click on **Add identity provider**.

[image]

2)select **identity provider** that you need to use

[image]

For more information refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad)